# XlsxWriter - Chart Column and Legend Color Mismatch

Tags: python, charts, colors, legend, xlsxwriter

I am working with`xlsxwriter` in `python`. I have created some charts however the color mismatches. I am trying to set colors as required for my work, however, the `legend colors` are not matched.
I need to make the second column `green` but in the legends section it turns red. Here is the chart that I am getting-
[image]

Here is the code that i am using:

```
chart8 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

chart8.add_series({'name':'RO',
                   'categories': [sheet_name, a, 0, b, 0],
                   'values':     [sheet_name, a, 1, b, 1],
                   'data_labels': {'value': True}, 
                   'points':[{'fill': {'color': 'blue','transparency':30}}, 
                             {'fill': {'color': 'blue','transparency':30}}]})

chart8.add_series({'name':'Planning',
                   'categories': [sheet_name, a, 0, b, 0],
                   'values':     [sheet_name, a, 2, b, 2],
                   'data_labels': {'value': True}, 
                   'points':[{'fill': {'color': 'lime','transparency':20}}, 
                             {'fill': {'color': 'lime','transparency':20}}]})

chart8.set_legend({'position': 'bottom'})

worksheet.insert_chart('G'+str(a), chart8)

worksheet.insert_chart(0, 6, chart8)
```

I tried to find the reason but could not find much. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to set colors as required for my work, however, the legend colors are not matched.

The reason for this is that you are setting the formatting for the "points" of the data rather than the entire series. So Excel still shows the default series format in the legend.

The fix is easy, you just need to specify the "fill" for the entire series, rather than just for the points in the series:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


# Write some data to add to plot on the chart.
worksheet.write_column('A1', ['New', 'Site'])
worksheet.write_column('B1', [8, 7])
worksheet.write_column('C1', [22, 9])

# Create a new Chart object.
chart8 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

# Set the sheet values.
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
a = 0
b = 1

chart8.add_series({'name':'RO',
                   'categories': [sheet_name, a, 0, b, 0],
                   'values': [sheet_name, a, 1, b, 1],
                   'data_labels': {'value': True},
                   'fill': {'color': 'blue', 'transparency': 30}})

chart8.add_series({'name':'Planning',
                   'categories': [sheet_name, a, 0, b, 0],
                   'values': [sheet_name, a, 2, b, 2],
                   'data_labels': {'value': True},
                   'fill': {'color': 'lime', 'transparency': 20}})

chart8.set_legend({'position': 'bottom'})

worksheet.insert_chart(0, 6, chart8)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This totally worked! I had to use points for some other charts. I didn't realize that I was doing this for all of them.

Comment: For Pie and Doughtnut style charts in Excel you need to use points to define individual colors. However all other chart types in Excel use series. You can still use points to set individual elements of non-pie charts but that is a rarer usage.